# Numpy image processing: sub-matrix extraction

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, region

I have 500 images with a dimension of 800x600 so in one batched numpy array I get a shape of `(500, 800, 600)`. I reshape this to `(500, 800*600)` for flattening, so I get an array of shape `(500, 480000)`.

Let's assume I want to process something on sub-regions of the image. I could easily extract a 100x100 pixel sub-region out of one image, let's say the first, with `array[0][0:100*100]` getting `array[0][0:10000]`...but how do I do this for a whole batch?

When I try to `array[0:50][0:100*100]` for getting sub-regions of the first 50 pictures in a whole I always get wrong results.

`array[0][0:10000]` for a sub-region of one single image has the right shape of `(10000,)` but

`array[0:50][0:100*100]` for a batch of 50 images has a shape of `(50, 480000)` instead of `(50, 10000)` what I really want to get the first sub-region of 50 images at once.

Comment: If you don't *flatten* it first it would be ```a[:50,:100,:100]```.

Comment: I've deleted my answer: while `array[:50, :10000]` would do what you're trying to achieve with `array[0:50][0:100*100]`, I suspect that you'd be better off *not* reshaping the array and instead using the slice `a[:50,:100,:100]` suggested by wwii. The two slices return different elements and the latter seems like a better interpretation of the word 'region'.

Comment: What are you trying to extract - the pixels from the top left 100x100 *window* from each individual image or just the first 10000 pixels from each flattened image?

Comment: ..the top left 100x100 window and so on from each individual image, so your suggestion is best and correct without flattening it first. You could create an answer, I would accept (:

Comment: To anyone reading this in '20. What is the fastest way to extract a varied image range from each batch? Is there a method without for loop? Ex: First image a[0,:100, :100], second image b[1, 100:150, 120:160].